# Suggestion in Deployment of ASP.NET Core Web API in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a ASP.NET Core Web API planning to deploy in AWS, I don't have enough background in AWS what is the good package to subscribe in AWS?

My option is Amazon EC2 or Cloud Computing or there is other package for Web API? And my other concern is I also have files to upload by the client need at least of 1 or 2 TB of cloud storage. Can I connect the Cloud Storage services of Amazon to Amazon EC2. I really don't how to start.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at Elastic Beanstalk (EB) as explained in [Creating and deploying .NET applications on Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.html). EB is AWS **Platform as a Service** (Paas) offering which allows you to deploy your code, without managing much or any of EC2 instances, load balancers, security groups and more.

Alternatively, if you can run your app in a **docker container**, maybe it would be easier to deploy it using [ECS Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/AWS_Fargate.html). EB can also be used to deploy dockerized applications.

For storage you can use [EFS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/index.html) if you require **filesystem-like storage** that can be shared across multiple instances, containers or lambda functions.